# Use onCLICK but fallback to HREF if right-clicked

Tags: javascript, html

If a user clicks a link, a pop up window should open.

Here is our current.html

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('important.html', '_blank', 'width=900,height=600');>
```

That works great but, `href="#"` prevents the page from going anywhere.

I want to handle a situation where the user possibly **right-clicks** the link and chooses **Open Link in New Tab**.

Currently, a new tab of *current.html* will open, instead of *important.html* - because of `href="#"`

...changing our href to `href="important.html"` is not feasible when the user does-not right click, as a new window from our onclick, and identical new tab from our href will be triggered.

How can I set href separately for right-click use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the default anchor click behaviour if your onclick event returns false:

```html
<a href="important.html" onclick="window.open('important.html', '_blank', 'width=900,height=600'); return false">link</a>
```

That way you can have both left and right click functions covered.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `href="important.html"` so that right click will work as normal, and then change your `onClick` so that it prevents the default action on left click:

```
function click() {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default anchor action.
  window.open('important.html', '_blank', 'width=900,height=600')
}
```

then set the onClick:

```
<a href="important.html" onclick="click()">link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `return false;` will prevent the default behaviour of the link taking place. When using **Open in new tab** it use the default behaviour.

```
<a href="important.html" onclick="window.open('important.html', '_blank', 'width=900,height=600'); return false;">Link</a>
```